# Can Varnish automatically determine which storage medium should be used to cache an object?

Tags: cache, varnish

For instance, I have an incredibly slow and archaic backend provider with requests regularly taking in the tens of seconds.  We also have a machine with moderate memory and large storage.  Ideally, I'd like to use *both* memory and storage in order to serve requests.

I found:

https://info.varnish-software.com/blog/partitioning-your-varnish-cache

But that seems to imply I have to manually split the data between the two, which seems challenging?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your architecture? You talk about storing objects in memory and on disk. You also refer to a really slow backend?
Why would you want to serve objects from disk & memory? Is it because you don't have enough memory storage available?

Comment: Yeah.  So we have a platform that serves ~250GB of data that is easily cacheable.  This is too much to store in memory at the price point we're willing to spend, but getting a 250GB disk is really cheap.  We have some hot data that's accessed on almost every visit (think static javascript / images) and so it would be good to serve some things from memory.

Comment: All you need to worry about is storage on disk.  What is most used will be in memory, ie the disk cache.

Comment: Oh, that's cool!  So I just have a single ~250GB cache on disk.  Then leave it to the OS to optimise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comments by Gerard H. Pille, the operating system's page cache will make sure the *hot data* is stored in memory.

### File stevedore

In terms of Varnish this means you can use the `file` stevedore to store the objects.

Here how you would configure this:

```
varnishd -s file,/var/lib/varnish/storage,250G
```

> I only focused on the `-s` parameter in the example above. In reality, there will be a lot of parameters used for `varnihsd`.

### Combining malloc & file

If you have a very clear indication what content will only live in memory, you can define multiple *stevedors*, as illustrated below:

```
varnishd -s disk=file,/var/lib/varnish/storage,250G -s memory=malloc,32G
```

In *VCL*, you can then to the following:

```
sub backend_response {
    if(beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "^(image|video)/") {
        set beresp.storage = "file";
    } else {
        set beresp.storage = "memory";
    }
}
```

### File stevedore limitations

The `file` stevedore has the capability of caching a lot of data. The main problem is that it is prone to disk fragmentation over time.

We've seen `file`-based setups perform really poorly overtime, primarily due to fragmentation.

Another downside is that the operating system's page cache is left guessing on what the right content is that should fit into memory.

And finally, although disks are persistent, the `file` stevedore isn't: as soon as you restart *Varnish* the contents of your cache are gone.

### Massive Storage Engine

At *Varnish Software*, we developed *Massive Storage Engine*, which is an advanced *stevedore* that tackles the issues that `file` has.

See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/mse/ for more information.

> Disclaimer: `mse` is a proprietary stevedore that is part of *Varnish Enterprise*. It requires a commercial license, but there are official machine images for *AWS*, *Azure* & *GCP* where you pay by the hour without having to purchase a license key upfront.

*MSE* is a lot more configurable and was designed with anti-fragmentation in mind. The memory cache doesn't rely on the operating system's page cache and performs better than the standard `malloc` implementation in Varnish.

The persistence layer can be tailored to your needs, based on multiple storage locations. There is also a module that allows you to select specific storage devices from VCL (see https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/vmods/mse/).

And finally, the *memory governor* feature automatically scales the memory size, based on memory requirements of other parts of Varnish. See https://docs.varnish-software.com/varnish-cache-plus/features/mse/memory_governor/